# Netsuite: Scriptable Templates - Getting Parent Customer Name

Tags: netsuite

I need to create a scriptable template where, among other details, it builds out a url and passes the company name. This email template will be sent via a Job (which from what i could find is an entity in Netsuite). I am getting an unexpected error when trying to preview the template so I removed all my urls and just started trying to output what I am going to try and encode in the url.

One thing I am trying to pull into the url eventually is the Customer, which has the ID of 'parent' on the Job record. My template was a `CRMSDK` template and when I convert it the tool converts `<NLPARENT>` to be

```
<#if (entity.stage)?has_content && (entity.parent)?has_content>${entity.parent}<#else>${company.parent}</#if>
```

If I leave this code in the template and remove everything else, I still get the unexpected error. I don't really understand what this is, just that Netsuite added it when converting.

If I remove everything and just use `${entity.parent}` to try and displace the Customer Name, then I still get the unexpected error. If I use `${company.parent}` I do not get the unexpected error, but I also do not get the Customer.

When I can solve this problem, the eventual statement I want to encode is basically this:

```
<#if entity.parent.parent != "">${entity.parent.parent} +' : '+${entity.parent}<#else>${entity.parent}</#if>
```

What my intent is with the above code is to get the Customer off the job (id of parent) and check if it has a parent (aka the Customer is a child of another Customer record). If it is, then I want to output the Parent Company : Child Company.

Any help to get to this point would be great. If I can get past this, then I am confident I can get my url encoding working.

EDIT: I have received revisions that were little more than capitalization but no answers/comments to help solve this issue. Can anyone assist in this?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate this is a long time after you posted but wondered if you ever resolved it and thought I'd offer up a suggestion.

If I've understood you correctly, you want to know if the customer associated with a job has a parent?

If so, I would suggest that information is not in scope at the point you are accessing it.

It would make sense, to me, to add a custom_field to the job (aka Project) that sources / filters using the parent field on the Project. (so jack in the parent's parent in to the custom field)
You would then be able to access the custom_field directly.

I'm wary to direct you "specifically" because I've not worked a huge amount on templates but I suspect you're getting your customer / job (project) / entities confused.

The current, in scope record, is typically ${record} when I've had to work on templates (albeit advanced print).
So you may also find ${record.parent} would work but again, fields on the parent would not be in scope.

You may find the Records Browser useful if you don't already know about it, try the NetSuite help for the url as it changes each release.

Comment: I really wish I had thought of this sooner! We have redone our system and this piece is no longer done in Netsuite but you are dead on! Now as I reread what I wrote and what you are saying I was digging too many levels down in what I was writing. A custom field would have worked perfectly.

Comment: Such a shame and annoying I hadn't seen it sooner :(
The NetSuite User Group also has items by myself relating to Adv / Print that digs in to this if you want to see more information about Freemarker and how it fits in to NetSuite.